# auto update stackoverflow pages?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, live-refresh

Are `stackoverflow` pages ( such as `Questions`, main pages of a posted question, profile page) auto-update?

If so, what is the update interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are stackoverflow pages ( such as Questions, main pages of a posted question, profile page) auto-update?

Yes. Not exact auto update but it will give you notification at the top of the questions list. Like this:

> [image]

> If so, what is the update interval?

If you are in the *newest* tab > when a new question is added.
If you are in *active* tab > When a new question is added or a question is updated.

Comment: Perfect and plain answer, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a new question is posted a notification like `x question with new activity` is appeared.

> [image]

Internally there is no time defined for page refreshment. It is depend on the new post arrival.

Such notification facility is only for the users with reputation more than 50.